# How to pull multiple rows into columns?

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr

Consider the following dataframe:

```
data_frame(
col1 = c("2017", "June",   "New", 10, 30),
col2 = c("2018", "July",   "Old", 20, 50),
name = c(NA, NA, NA, "dog", "cat")
)

# A tibble: 5 x 3
  col1  col2  name 
1 2017  2018  NA   
2 June  July  NA   
3 New   Old   NA   
4 10    20    dog  
5 30    50    cat
```

I'd like to transform it to this output:

```
## Year Month  Type name Amount
## 2017 June   New  dog  10
## 2018 July   Old  dog  20
## 2017 June   New  cat  30
## 2018 July   Old  cat  50
```

I have tried using pivot longer, but it has a hard time doing multiple *rows* as well as dealing with the dead space with the NA.

Comment: Maybe my coffee hasn't kicked in yet, but I'm not following the logic for reshaping this. How are you matching up the name column with the others, and what do you plan on for the NAs?

Comment: You essentially have two different data sets jammed together in two different directions. The Year/Month/Type data are organize rowwise, followed by two rows of dog/cat data arranged columnwise. A large amount of special handling is required just to pull these apart and reformat them into something more workable, to such an extent that I doubt a solution to your example would apply to the larger data set. TLDR; you need to separate and/or reformat the source data before attempting to transform it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I worked this out by identifying 3 types of data that are all smashed into the one data frame, then separating them. Like @jdobres says above, this might not scale beyond this toy example, but should be a start.

From what I can tell, you have 3 types of data that you can pull out based on regex searching in `col1`:

1. Years, identified by `^20\\d{2}$` (will need to be adjusted if you include 19xx years, etc
2. Months, identified by non-digit characters
3. Names, identified either by type of value in `col1` or by non-`NA` `name`

Filter and reshape them so their data matches the shapes shown in your desired output:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

yrs_df <- df %>% 
  filter(grepl("^20\\d{2}$", col1)) %>%
  gather(key, value = year) %>%
  filter(!is.na(year))

name_df <- df %>%
  filter(!is.na(name)) %>%
  gather(key, value, -name)
```

The months get reshaped a second time, because you have both `month` and `type` in the same columns, and want to separate them as well.

```r
month_df <- df %>%
  filter(grepl("^\\D", col1)) %>%
  mutate(col_type = row_number()) %>%
  gather(key, value, -col_type) %>%
  filter(!is.na(value)) %>%
  spread(key = col_type, value, sep = "") %>%
  rename(month = col_type1, type = col_type2)

yrs_df
#> # A tibble: 2 x 2
#>   key   year 
#>   <chr> <chr>
#> 1 col1  2017 
#> 2 col2  2018
name_df
#> # A tibble: 4 x 3
#>   name  key   value
#>   <chr> <chr> <chr>
#> 1 dog   col1  10   
#> 2 cat   col1  30   
#> 3 dog   col2  20   
#> 4 cat   col2  50
month_df
#> # A tibble: 2 x 3
#>   key   month type 
#>   <chr> <chr> <chr>
#> 1 col1  June  New  
#> 2 col2  July  Old
```

Then join everything back by key (could also use `purrr::reduce` since all joins are on the same column)

```r
yrs_df %>%
  inner_join(month_df, by = "key") %>%
  inner_join(name_df, by = "key")
#> # A tibble: 4 x 6
#>   key   year  month type  name  value
#>   <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>
#> 1 col1  2017  June  New   dog   10   
#> 2 col1  2017  June  New   cat   30   
#> 3 col2  2018  July  Old   dog   20   
#> 4 col2  2018  July  Old   cat   50
```

All that said—there's probably a larger problem here that jumbles up all your data like this that could be solved further upstream.

Comment: this was a terrible, terrible file i know. What I really liked about your approach was how simple it was - take apart and clean each piece. I was trying to do too much in one pipe!